# What does "Googs" really mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery

In *Glass Onion A Knives Out Mystery* (2022), Duke was holding his phone, smiling, as billionaire Miles and Birdie danced:

> Miles: Hey. Duke's smiling. There it is, there's my guy. What's going
> on? You look like you got good news.

Miles approaches Duke and Duke shows him his phone.:

> Duke: I was wondering why my **Googs** are blowing up. The views on my
> channel are off the charts. You gotta see this.

What does "Googs" really mean?

Comment: Could it be a reference to "my droogs" in *Clockwork Orange* ?  The main character Alex calls his gang members droogs ?   Comment because its a guess, no evidence.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Duke likes to refer to his [preset Google News alerts](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/4815696?hl=en) as his 'Googs'. It's not really clear why.

> **DUKE:** *It's my goog alerts, I've got one for all you guys, Whiskey, sports I like.
> General interests.*
>
> DING! SHHHHTICK. Lionel looks at Duke's phone.
>
> **LIONEL:** *You have **a google alert** for the word "movie?"*
>
> <sup><sub>[Glass Onion - Screenplay](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Glass-Onion-A-Knives-Out-Mystery-Read-The-Screenplay.pdf)</sub></sup>

Comment: probably trying to sound "cool"and "casual".

Comment: or trying to appeal to younger audiences by using the "Totally Radical" trope. Nobody really says "googs" https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TotallyRadical

Comment: @Luciano - I think you mean "cas". That's what the cool kids say

Comment: He might just be merging the phrase "Google alerts" -- "le" and "al" are similar sounds, so it becomes "googalert". Then it expands to "goog alert" and "goog" becomes a word. This is a common way that language changes.

Comment: @Luciano: IDK about "appeal to younger audiences", maybe "signal to older audiences that this character is or acts young and cool."